# SQL - when NULL set value

Tags: sql, oracle, null

I have the following SQL query:

```
SELECT item, count(item)
FROM tableX
WHERE salesman='Mr.Doe'
GROUP BY item
ORDER BY count(item)
```

So it would look like this:

```
     item  | amount
-------------------------
item A     |  10
item B     |   7
item c     |   5
```

How can i display ('no item' and 0)  IF salesman 'Mr.Doe' has NO items? it should look like this:

```
      item  | amount
-------------------------
 no item    |  0
```

Comment: There is no question here... Are you asking _how_ to handle a `null` value or are looking for us to expand you query to account for 0 and/or `null`?

Comment: Also, SQL supports the `if/else` structures...

Comment: From what client is this query being run?  If it's from a web app, it would be easier to handle with application code.

Comment: do you have a table which holds your salespeople's details?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a little complex to do in standard SQL.  But you can.  Here is one way, using `union all`:

```
SELECT item, count(item)
FROM tableX
WHERE salesman='Mr.Doe'
GROUP BY item
union all
select 'no item', 0
from dual
where not exists (select 1 from tableX where salesman = 'Mr.Doe')
ORDER BY count(item)
```

Comment: thank you for your reply Gordon Linoff. i just had the idea to do this with CASE: CASE WHEN count(item) is null THEN 0 ELSE count(item) END
and for item: CASE WHEN item is null THEN 'no item' ELSE item END. Is this possible? :S thank you.

Comment: @Jen688 - Yes, that is possible but, the answer Gordon provided is much more easily read and concise.  I would you that.  Oh, and Gordon, +1.